# How to get the latest release tag of a specific submodule in .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two submodules in my repo. My `.gitmodules` look like this:

```bash
[submodule "strong_sort/deep/reid"]
    path = strong_sort/deep/reid
    url = https://github.com/KaiyangZhou/deep-person-reid
[submodule "yolov7"]
    path = yolov7
    url = https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7
```

When running `git tag` I get the following:

```bash
v.2.0
v1.0
v3.0
v4.0
v5.0
v6.0
yolov7
```

How do I get the latest release tag of a specific submodule? I know I can run `git submodule foreach` but how is it supposed to be used when you have multiple submodules?

For the specific case of Yolov7 for example I would like to see its latest release tag: `v0.1` (https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/tags) atm of writing this post

Comment: `git submodule foreach git describe`?

Comment: I get the following when running you command: `Entering 'strong_sort/deep/reid'
tagName
Entering 'yolov7'
tagName` Not what I am looking for

Comment: Then `git submodule foreach git log -1 --tags --pretty=%D`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the latest release tag @jthill

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I've lost faith that the goalposts will ever stop moving.

Comment: You comment is the solution i am looking for @jthill

Comment: The answer however isn't complete. How do I get the latest release tag of a specific module. This: 
`git submodule foreach git log -1 --tags --pretty=%D
` gives me the latest release version for each of them

Answer (score 1):

Here are three tags for an arbitrary repository:

```
v1.3
pre-rewrite
alpha
```

Which one of these is the latest tag?

The answer to the above question (that there isn't an answer to the question unless you come up with an answer to the question) is the answer to your question.   Despite the goofy-face emoticon, I don't mean this sarcastically or sardonically or whatever: basically, *you* have to pick out what *you* mean by "latest tag", and then the problem is easy:

Remember that a submodule is simply a Git repository.  As such, you can enter that submodule and run `git tag` or `git tag -l` and get a list of tags.  It's up to you to figure out which of these is the *latest* tag, by whatever means you want to use.

The superproject in control of a submodule never uses the submodule's tags directly.  It hardly even uses *branch names* in the submodule (there are a few oddball cases with `git submodule update` subcommands, including `--remote` variants, that can use them indirectly but not directly): instead, each *gitlink* in the superproject controls which submodule commit will be checked out by `git submodule update` or a recursive checkout.  But you can, once the submodule is cloned and has a commit checked out, use `git submodule foreach` to run arbitrary commands—not limited to Git commands—*in* each submodule, and those commands can select some commit to check out in that submodule.

Having moved the submodule's current commit to some other commit, you can then `git add` the submodule in the superproject.  So, let's suppose you have some Python program `sort-and-pick-latest-tag.py` that picks the latest one.  Then the set of commands to run *in* the submodule is:

```
latest=$(python sort-and-pick-latest-tag.py)
# $latest is now the "latest tag"
echo latest: $latest
git switch --detach $latest
```

which you can express as a single-line command minus the `echo` like this:

```
git switch --detach $(python sort-and-pick-latest-tag.py)
```

Give that whole string (in single quotes to protect it from the shell interpreting it, if you're using a POSIX-style shell like bash) to `git submodule foreach` and Git will run that command in each submodule.  (Add `--recursive` if desired, but note that this makes the next step more complicated.)  Then just add each submodule to update the index / staging-area gitlink.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the latest release tag

Comment: Still the same issue: is "rel-delta" newer or older than "rel-0.4"? Again, *you* must decide this. Write some software that encodes your decision, and then the rest is easy.